# How can I perform an ANOVA with one within subjects and one between subjects factor in Python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, anova

I am analyzing heart rate variability between two different conditions (drug and placebo) that was measured at 2 different timepoints (before and after drug administration).  The participants recieved either drug or placebo and therefore this is a between subjects factor, but the timepoints is a within subjects factor.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = ols('RMSSD ~ C(drug) + C(segname) + C(drug):C(segname)', data=df).fit()
sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
```

I get the below table, which could make sense but I want to verify that I'm inputting the factors correctly because I don't think I am.

```
sum_sq  df  F   PR(>F)
C(drug) 5.692727e-03    1.0 7.931049    0.005921
C(segname)  1.250657e-03    1.0 1.742403    0.190040
C(drug):C(segname)  3.482489e-07    1.0 0.000485    0.982473
Residual    6.747106e-02    94.0    NaN NaN
```